# Плавное появление блока

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

У меня есть такой участок разметки (сразу оговорюсь, что разметку делал не я, ее мне в качестве темплейта предоставили, и плясать нужно от нее):

```
<div class="modal-view-bg">
    <div class="modal-view-container">
        <div id="login_modal" class="modal-view show-modal1 disN">
            <div class="modal-title">
                <div>LOGIN</div>
                <a href="/"><span class="modal-close"></span></a>
            </div>
            <form method="post" asp-page-handler="Login">
                <input type="email" name="Email" class="input-modal mrB20" placeholder="Email account">
                <input type="password" name="Password" class="input-modal mrB20" placeholder="Password">
                <a href="/Identity/Reset"><span class="btn-modal-text">Reset password</span></a>
                <button class="button-modal color-red">Login</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Контейнер с айдишником `id="login_modal"` отвечает за некую форму. Появление этой формы происходит путем переключения класса `disN` в `disB`

```
.disN {
    display: none !important;
}

.disB {
    display: block !important;
}
```

Механика такова, что при загрузке страницы, `disN` должен сменится в `disB`и форма анимированно появляется.

я это реализовал с помощью JQuery так:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        document.getElementById("login_modal").classList.remove("disN");
        document.getElementById("login_modal").classList.toggle("disB");
        $("login_modal").fadeIn("slow");
  });
</script>
```

но никакого плавного появления не происходит.

Подскажите, где я что не так сделал?

Comment: добавьте Вашу css в вопрос.

Comment: @Denis640Kb добавил

Comment: ну так изначально установлен disB а не disN вот toggle его и удаляет

Comment: @ValeraKvip, прошу прощения, это ошибка при копировании на стак, там изначально disN. Сейчас исправлю.

Comment: $("#login_modal") решетку забыл и убедись что display: block  добавилось

Answer (score 2):

Вы можете использовать добавление стиля через `jquery` Но старайтесь не смешивать `js` и `jquery` (В конце пример как надо на `jquery`)
Например:

```js
    $(document).ready(function () {
        login.onclick = function (){
            document.getElementById("login_modal").classList.remove("disN");
            $('#login_modal').addClass('disB').fadeOut(0).fadeIn(3000);
        };
    });
```

```css
    .disN {
        display: none !important;
    }
    .disB {
        display: block !important;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="modal-view-bg">
    <div class="modal-view-container">
        <div id="login_modal" class="modal-view show-modal1 disN">
            <div class="modal-title">
                <div>LOGIN</div>
                <a href="/"><span class="modal-close"></span></a>
            </div>
            <form method="post" asp-page-handler="Login">
                <input type="email" name="Email" class="input-modal mrB20" placeholder="Email account">
                <input type="password" name="Password" class="input-modal mrB20" placeholder="Password">
                <a href="/Identity/Reset"><span class="btn-modal-text">Reset password</span></a>
                <button class="button-modal color-red">Login</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button id="login">Появись!</button>
</div>
```

Как альтернатива `fadeIn` Вы можете использовать `@keyframes` в css.

```js
    $(document).ready(function () {
        login.onclick = function (){
            document.getElementById("login_modal").classList.remove("disN");
            document.getElementById("login_modal").classList.add("disB");
        };
    });
```

```css
    @keyframes showBlock {
        0% {
            opacity: 0;
        }
        100% {
            opacity: 1;
        }
    }
    .disN {
        display: none !important;
    }
    .disB {
        display: block !important;
        animation: showBlock 3s linear forwards;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="modal-view-bg">
    <div class="modal-view-container">
        <div id="login_modal" class="modal-view show-modal1 disN">
            <div class="modal-title">
                <div>LOGIN</div>
                <a href="/"><span class="modal-close"></span></a>
            </div>
            <form method="post" asp-page-handler="Login">
                <input type="email" name="Email" class="input-modal mrB20" placeholder="Email account">
                <input type="password" name="Password" class="input-modal mrB20" placeholder="Password">
                <a href="/Identity/Reset"><span class="btn-modal-text">Reset password</span></a>
                <button class="button-modal color-red">Login</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button id="login">Появись!</button>
</div>
```

На `jquery`:

```js
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#login').click(function () {
            $('#login_modal').removeClass('disN');
            $('#login_modal').addClass('disB').fadeOut(0).fadeIn(3000);
        });
    });
```

```css
    .disN {
        display: none !important;
    }
    .disB {
        display: block !important;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="modal-view-bg">
    <div class="modal-view-container">
        <div id="login_modal" class="modal-view show-modal1 disN">
            <div class="modal-title">
                <div>LOGIN</div>
                <a href="/"><span class="modal-close"></span></a>
            </div>
            <form method="post" asp-page-handler="Login">
                <input type="email" name="Email" class="input-modal mrB20" placeholder="Email account">
                <input type="password" name="Password" class="input-modal mrB20" placeholder="Password">
                <a href="/Identity/Reset"><span class="btn-modal-text">Reset password</span></a>
                <button class="button-modal color-red">Login</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button id="login">Появись!</button>
</div>
```

Comment: @MaximLensky Это взято из примера автора. Не гоже переписывать всё.

Comment: @MaximLensky было множество случаев когда меня лично за такую самодеятельность наказывали.

Comment: @MaximLensky Значит я такой уникальный =((( Добавил пример на чистом `jquery` в конце. Проверим.

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо всем кто откликнулся, но я разобрался сам. Я неправильно использовал функцию `fadeIn`

Перписал скрипт так:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        document.getElementById("login_modal").classList.remove("disN");
        $("#login_modal").fadeIn(2500, function () {
            document.getElementById("login_modal").classList.toggle("disB")
        });
    });
```

все заработало.

Ваши решения тоже имеют право на жизнь, но они слишком сложные.